# SN1 reaction in a polar aprotic solvent

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm seeking a $\ce{S_N1}$ reaction that happens in a polar aprotic solvent.
Do you know any good simple $\ce{S_N1}$ reactions which satisfy the condition?

Comment: Try something that forms a tertiary benzyl carbocation in the reaction.

Answer (score -1):

I think something like potassium 2-methylpropan-2-olate and 3-bromopentane in $\ce{SO(CH3)2}$ should do the trick.